# IllegalArgumentException Fragment in a Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem with a Fragment.
There is a Dialog inside a Fragment, and a Fragment inside this Dialog.
But when I add the second Fragment, there is an `IllegalArgumentException : No view found for id ***** (fr.*****:id/container_list_collections) for fragment FragmentCollectionVignette`.

**FragmentHP.java**

```
public class FragmentHP extends Fragment {

/** Bouton Ajouter à **/
private Button btAddTo;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vueFragmentHP = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hp, container, false);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_dernier_ajout, new FragmentDerniersAjoutsHP()).commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_collections, new FragmentCollectionsHP()).commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_ebooks, new FragmentEbooksHP()).commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_games, new FragmentGamesHP()).commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_software, new FragmentSoftwareHP()).commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_digital_creation, new FragmentDigitalCreationHP()).commit();

    btAddTo = (Button) vueFragmentHP.findViewById(R.id.bt_collections);

    btAddTo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_to, null);
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            Button btValider = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_add_to);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_list_collections, new FragmentCollectionVignette()).commit();
        }
    });

    return vueFragmentHP;
}
```

}

**dialog_add_to.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_add_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_to"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_choose_collection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/choose_collection"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_add_to"/>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container_list_collections"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_choose_collection"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/bt_add_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/valider"
        android:layout_below="@id/container_list_collections"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What is the problem ?
(Sorry for my very bad english)

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project? Sometimes changing resources does not regenerate R file.

Comment: Yes but I have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is in this line

```
getFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container_list_collections, new FragmentCollectionVignette())
.commit();
```

change this to

```
this.getActivity()
.getFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container_list_collections, new FragmentCollectionVignette())
.commit()
```

Comment: You want to render a different fragment on button click of dialog.

Comment: I want to insert a fragment in a Dialog.

Comment: Then please use dialogFragment .

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DialogFragment can not be attached to a container view

Comment: I use DialogFragment and I change to getChildFragmentManager(). Thanks !